# Type error: Plotting an array including tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just gonna solve and plot a nonlinear equation with matplotlib, but there is an error saying:

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Can you help me fix it?...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

r = np.arange(-100, 100, step=0.01, dtype=float)

def equation(p,r0):
    x = p
    r = r0
    return (r * x + np.power(x,3)- np.power(x,5))

temp = []

for i in r:
    x = fsolve(equation, 0, args=(i,))
    temp.extend((i,x))

my_array = np.array(temp)

#print(my_array)
x, y = zip(*my_array)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: you need to use `append` instead of `extend` to create a 2d array. But you probably have another bug somewhere since all your `x` values are `0`... And finally note that you can use transposition rather than `zip` for the same result: `x, y = my_array.T`

Comment: @Julien: Thanks. I've applied the replacement you said. The error is resolved but the program returns nothing!

Comment: What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: @Julien: A 2-D plot to draw the set of tuples whose each one's first item is an element from `r` and the second one is the output of `dsolve` as `x`, corresponding to that particular `r`.

Comment: Are you running it in command line or interactively? It works for me interactively... If you do it from the command line you probably need to pose the program after the plot to let you see the figure before it closes it automatically. Dunno how to do that since I never use the command line for plots, but I'm sure you can find the answer in other posts...

Comment: @Julien: I'd even tried from `cmd`, but there is still neither the expected result nor any thrown error.

Comment: Well it works... you just need to figure out where the figure is plotted in your interpreter, can't really help with that... Or you can try to save the figure and then visualize it outside of python...

Answer (score 0):

As @Julien said, you must use `append` instead of `extend`. Furthermore, I guess you can't see the result because there is no `plt.show()` in your snippet. You need to add that right after `plt.plot(x,y)`. Then, the output will be:

[image]

You better change your initial guess to something else because `0` is the answer for the equation for all `r`. As an example, here is the result for `2`:

[image]